# how to count application successfull launches programmatically android?

Tags: android

I want to count my application launches and after some launches i need to request user to give feed back.So how to count launches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that if you use the onCreate you don't count too many starts. If you call onCreate (in stead of something like "onConfigurationChanged") when the device is changed from portrait to landscape, or if someone slides out the keyboard, then you'll get too many 'hits' on your counter!

You can find a sharedpreference example here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

And check for calling the oncreate here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a shared preference for your application which holds the Application launch count.
2. In the onCreate() of the Main Activity check value stored in the shared preference whether it is equal to the amount of launches you need if so do your operation else increment the value in the sharedpreference.